# How to compare integer literals?

Tags: powershell

I want to compare a size with a threshold that will be input by the user or be set by default if no input. the threshold should be in GB, although, user shouldnt have to enter unit.

here is the code i have

```
param($threshold)
if(!$threshold){$threshold = 20} #threshold is GB
#write-output "$threshold GB"  

Import-Module SqlServer

$Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$Analysis_Server.connect("$server")

$Size = $Analysis_Server.Databases[$cube].EstimatedSize

if ($size -ge 1GB)
{
    $newSize = [pscustomobject]@{
        Size = $size/1GB; Unit = 'GB'
    }
}
elseif ($size -ge 1MB)
{
    $newSize = [pscustomobject]@{
        Size = $size/1MB; Unit = 'MB'
    }
}
elseif ($size -ge 1KB)
{
    $newSize = [pscustomobject]@{
        Size = $size/1KB; Unit = 'KB'
    }
}
else
{
    $newSize = [pscustomobject]@{
        Size = $size; Unit = 'B'
    }
}
if($newSize.Size -gt $threshold) {"exceeded the threshold!"}
```

the last part `if($newSize.Size -gt $threshold) {"exceeded the threshold!"}` doesnt work because the unit is not specified. if i use integer literal for testing purposes, i am getting the following strange output of the threshold print if i set the threshold as an integer literal like this: `20GB`: 21474836480

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(!$threshold)` with the $?

Comment: @js2010 oh yes thats right, forgot to paste here in the post

Comment: You're also doing `write-output "$threshold GB"` in every case.

Comment: @js2010 hmm, what do you mean...i only see one write-output

Comment: But no matter what $threshhold is, you're going to write it.  It's outside the if statement.

Comment: @js2010 im confsued...how would it be written everytime?

Comment: @Cataster: I presume that the `write-output "$threshold GB"` is just for debugging / to display status information and not relevant to the problem at hand - I suggest you remove it so as to avoid confusion. What js2010 probably means is that the statement is executed unconditionally every time the script is executed (which you probably know and expect).

Comment: @mklement0 gotcha. ya it was just for debugging purposes :)

Comment: @mklement0 let me explain to you the requirement we have: we have whats called SSAS cubes/databases on our servers. recently the cube sizes have been getting too big on production and causing processing issues. i was tasked with writing a script that gets a report of all cubes on all servers we have and have a mechanism to check cube size vs system threshold. i am using Cim to get the server physical memory size (64 GB), which will be the default $threshold and multiplying by 0.7 to account for other system resources besides cubes.

Comment: @mklement0 continued...`$threshold = ((Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum /1gb)*0.7` .......the cubes we have are loaded into memory everytime they process and Microsoft resource told us 2.5x of cube size is approximately allocated in memory for the cube to process. so the formular for the cube size compared ot threshold would become, based on bytes to Bytes comparison per oberow's comment: `if($([math]::Round($Size*2.5, 2)) B > $([int]$threshold * 1GB)) {"threshold exceeded!"}`

Comment: @Cataster. I see, so it sounds like oberow's hint helped you solve your problem, right? As an aside: you don't need `$(...)` around your expressions, `(...)` is enough (faster and no side effects).

Comment: @mklement0 well idk if the number make sense. On google it gives ne the gb to byte calculation is scientific notation, and I dont see any similarity in the numbers generated by powershell  so idk if the calculation is being done right...I think I should deal with gb to gb comparison, much easier to tell if the conversion is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use same units for comparison

You probably want to use the same units when you compare `$newSize.Size` and `$threshold`. If `$threshold` is in GB and you want to convert to Bytes for example, you can do this: `($threshold * 1GB)`

## Gigabytes vs Gibibytes

Also, note the difference between Gigabytes and Gibibytes. In Powershell, the 1GB constant refers to a Gibibyte.

If you Google 1GB to Bytes, you'll get 1GB = 1,000,000,000 Bytes, which is correct for a Gigabyte.

Google Gibibyte to Bytes though, and you'll get what PowerShell uses, which is 1,073,741,824 Bytes.

Comment: ahh i see! well this solves one mystery. what about the comparison, how can i compare the size to threshold?

Comment: question: i decided to us ethe following threshold formula: ((Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum /1gb)*0.7.....my phyical memory size is 64GB....

........*0.7 to account for other memory resources..............now i have this comparison bytes to bytes: $([math]::Round($Size*2.5, 2)) B > $([int]$threshold * 1GB)...i outputted this and am getting the following values: 
6018455715 B < 48318382080 .... is that correct compared to their GB values? 2.24 GB .... 44.8 GB

Comment: @Cataster: The comparison looks correct to me, assuming $Size is in Bytes and $threshold is in Gibibytes. I'm not sure why you think that 6018455715 B corresponds to 2.24GB though, which it is not. Running `6018455715 / 1GB` in PowerShell gives you 5.6GB. I suspect you mean to say 5.6GB instead of 2.24GB though, because you forgot to multiply 2.24GB by 2.5...

Comment: @oberow oh thts right...I am multiplying by 2.5, thts whyyyy